# Is this an error or could be worded better in the Android docs?

Tags: android

If you guys take a look at this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#stop()

and read the description "Stops playback after playback has been stopped or paused." 
Would the correct description be "Stops playback if playback is paused or currently playing?" (Doesn't make sense to stop something that is already stopped)

I feel like this could clarify the stop method to future users of this class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it appears so.

Although it doesn't make sense to stop something that's stopped, it might still be useful to be able to call `stop()` without knowing whether it's stopped or not. If you look at the doc for `start()` and `pause()`, they seem to throw an exception only if there's a major problem, and not just if you're trying to change state to the current state. So I would expect `stop()` to be allowed in the stopped state.

But definitely the documentation is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that looks like an error for sure. It contradicts other parts of documentation of the same class:

In the class description of [android.media.MediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) on the same page, there is a [state diagram](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#StateDiagram),
and a paragraph of the explanation says:

> - Calling stop() **stops playback** and causes a MediaPlayer in the **Started, Paused, Prepared or PlaybackCompleted** state to enter the Stopped state.
>
>   - Once in the Stopped state, playback cannot be started until prepare() or prepareAsync() are called to set the MediaPlayer object
>       to the Prepared state again.
>   - Calling stop() has **no effect** on a MediaPlayer object that is **already in the Stopped state**.

(The source code of the method `stop()` is not very insightful, as it ha a native implementation.)